# DIV float:left; TROUBLE

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have trouble aligning the div's with the FLOAT:LEFT; tag.
Is there something wrong with the code I am overlooking?

The logo is supposed to be at the very left, and the two div bars on top of each other.

Thanks in advance.

```
<header id="head-01">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="nav-head-01"></div>
    <div class="nav-head-02"></div>
</header>

header#head-01 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
header#head-01 div.logo {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(238, 28, 36, 0.4);
}
header#head-01 div.nav-head-01 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 880px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(57, 59, 60, 0.3);
}
header#head-01 div.nav-head-02 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 880px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(142, 145, 148, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: I am unable to test this properly, but I think you should make `div.nav-head-01` float right and remove clear, and make `div.nav-head-02` float right and clear right (right only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `float` to make them appear next to each other, but you are also using `clear`, which prevents this.

Here is an example that will get you closer. The clears are gone, as are the floats on the two right-hand elements. Instead, a margin-left is added.

```
header#head-01 {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
header#head-01 div.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(238, 28, 36, 0.4);
}
header#head-01 div.nav-head-01 {
    width: 880px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 62.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(57, 59, 60, 0.3);
}
header#head-01 div.nav-head-02 {
    float: left;
    width: 880px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 62.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(142, 145, 148, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to user another div to wrap the 2 navs.

```
<header id="head-01">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-head-01"></div>
    <div class="nav-head-02"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And then float that div to left:

```
header#head-01 {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
header#head-01 div.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 2.5px;
    background-color: rgba(238, 28, 36, 0.4);
}

.nav-wrapper {
    float: left;
}
header#head-01 div.nav-head-01 {

    float: left;
    width: 880px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(57, 59, 60, 0.3);
}
header#head-01 div.nav-head-02 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 880px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(142, 145, 148, 0.3);
}
```

The result is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8G4y/)